# Initialization by constructor in c++

Tags: c++

I have question about constructor,
why following code works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class mycl
{
private:
    int a;
    //struct
    //{
        char b,c;
    //} ms;

public:
    mycl (int _a,char _b,char _c):a (_a), b (_b), c (_c){}

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    mycl slc (15, 'a', 'f');
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/wBgM1b

but there is a compilation error in this one

https://ideone.com/Yqxvzk

is it possible to initialize members of complex types this way?

p.s.
thank for translate and for answer.
sorry about wrong language

Comment: This is an english only site.

Comment: I've not understood the last word...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not in English.

Comment: Maybe you ment to post this to: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian

Comment: Try http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: 你写什么？我看不懂。was schreibst du? あなたは何を書いていますか？

Comment: Please include the code that generates an error into the question itself, not via a link to ideone.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to give your parameters different names. `mycl (int a, char b, char c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}` works just fine in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
mycl(int _a, char _b, char _c) : a(_a), ms{_b, _c} {}
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```